# Prevent buttons overlapping

Tags: html, css

This is my div structure. I'm having difficulties achieving the following.

How can I make all 3 buttons (Sub 1, Sub 2, Sub 3) visible and make the height of `DIV 1` to the height of its children buttons?

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/6/)

html:

```css
.sub {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lime;
}
.itmHolder {
  position: relative;
}
.Buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 8px;
}
.itmHolder:nth-child(2),
.itmHolder:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.og {
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="og">
  <div class="itmHolder">
    <div class="sub">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="sub">DIV 2</div>
    <div class="sub">
      <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 1</button>
      <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itmHolder">
    <button type="button" class="normalBtn">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: actually DIV1 has no children. Are you sure about this structure at all? Looks really weird

Comment: Use `display:inline-block;` on your `.sub` for starters. I'm not sure through why you have a 'div 1' and 'div 2' when no such elements appear in your expected outcome

Comment: @jbutler483 Why use `display:inline-block;` on `.sub`??

Comment: @jbutler483 your EDITED snippet is not same as my fiddle?

Comment: @Fergoso: I have merely placed your code into a snippet. If it does not contain other elements, place add these in.

Comment: @jbutler483 It's clear that you're after points and no assistance to resolving the actual issue. Anyways you shouldn't be editing stuff if you are not aware of what you're doing.

Comment: Points? Oh right you're chatting about rep. Well, you stop getting 'edit points' after **2k rep**. Not being boastful, but I've 7k rep in excess. Let's just say it was a while since I got +2 for an edit. [If you look at my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30101484/revisions), you can see I have placed your code in a snippet - there is no removal of text there. If there is content "missing", it is in fact that it was never there - maybe you didn't copy all or something. I have not altered the code in any way - I have simply presented it in a snippet.

Comment: @Fergoso: I honestly can't find anything (from the code that was originally present in the question) to be missing in the snippet. If you are referring to the extra `<!-- lang...` lines they are for the syntax highlighting and don't make any other difference to your code. Also, users who are above 2k rep do not get any extra rep points for editing :)

Comment: @Fergoso: You mean you wanted [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/fq0x9Lxs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I removed obsolete elements and css definitions and now it looks exactly like the image:

```css
.sub {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lime;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.itmHolder {
  position: relative;
}
.Buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 8px;
}
.og {
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="og">
    <div class="itmHolder">
      <div class="sub">
        <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="itmHolder">
      <button type="button" class="normalBtn">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/6/)

Comment: Your fiddle is same as mine.

Comment: sorry... anyway, just apply the code from the answer

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change your css a little:

```
.Buttons{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px 8px;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
}
.itmHolder > :nth-child(2) , .itmHolder > :nth-child(3){
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/7/

Answer (score 0):

I would have made somethin like that

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.subs {
  background-color: green;
}
.subs button {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="subs">
    <button>Sub1</button>
    <button>Sub2</button>
    <button>Sub3</button>
  </div>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your expected output. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/10/) could help you.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<div class="parent">
    <button>SUB1</button>
    <button>SUB2</button>
    <button>SUB3</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  background-color: lime;
}
div{
    text-align: center;
}
.parent button{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height: 55px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle is same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem and your markup is not understandable. Don't know why you have used `pos:abs` property. If you want as in your figure then, you don't need that much codes. Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/8/) .

**HTML**

```
<div class="make-center">
    <div class="sub">
        <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 3</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="normalBtn">Button</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.make-center {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.sub {
    background: lime;
}
.normalBtn,
.Buttons {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

The spacing between buttons are because of default button border ( browser's default rendering ).

Answer (score 0):

i hope you want like this type of menu

```
<ul class="itmHolder">
           <li>DIV 1</li>
           <li>DIV 2
           <ul class="sub">
               <li> <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 1</button></li>
               <li>          <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 2</button></li><li>
               <button type="button" class="Buttons">Sub 3</button></li>
                <button type="button" class="normalBtn">Button</button>
           </ul>
        </li>

</ul>
```

css

```
.itmHolder{ margin:0; padding:0;}
.itmHolder li{ display:inline-block; position:relative;}
.itmHolder li .sub{display:none; height:50px; background:lime; width:100%; position:absolute; width:500px;}
.itmHolder li:hover .sub {display:block;}
.itmHolder li:hover .sub button{height:50px; margin:0 2px;}
.normalBtn{top:50px;margin-left:250px;position:absolute}
```

use this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your css: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/9/)**

```
.itmHolder :nth-child(2) , .itmHolder :nth-child(3){
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```